# Asynchronous threading using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am learning multithreading in python and don't understand why the thread isn't acting asynchronous.

Here is my code.

```
def send_email():
    ....

thread1 = threading.Thread(name='thread1',target=send_email)
thread1.start()
return 'Email sent'
```

I don't understand why, but the thread1 is waiting until the target is completed and then coming to the next line.

Need help understanding this.